# How to deploy an iPad app to apple store?

Tags: objective-c, deployment, app-store

This client wants to deploy our app to apple store. Before this, i have worked upon either enterprise app or other clients deploy app to apple store themselves. Now, this client wants me to guide them step by step to deploy on to app store.
I googled and found few articles about that process. It would be good if someone can share the document or link they referred while doing so.
I have development profile as well as enterprise profile.

Please help me in this.

Comment: It's a good thing that you have your development profile. That means you are a developer who have access to Apple's online library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document should get you started in all the right directions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

If the account is set up properly and the actual app binary is there as well (and is working and was tested and all, you know), then the actual release shouldn't be all too difficult. You have to have icons and screenshots and descriptions and everything ready at the time when you release, but don't worry, you can always pause the release process and get back to it later if you realize you're missing anything.

Is this too general? Do you need any more specific answers (for more specific questions)?